# CONCAT is not working in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Cursor_Test;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE Cursor_Test()
BEGIN

  DECLARE Project_Number_val VARCHAR( 255 );
  DECLARE Project_List_val VARCHAR(255);



  DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
  DECLARE loop_cntr INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;


  DECLARE projects_cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Project_Id
    FROM Project_Details;


  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET no_more_rows = TRUE;


  OPEN projects_cur;
  select FOUND_ROWS() into num_rows;

  the_loop: LOOP

    FETCH  projects_cur
    INTO   Project_Number_val;


    IF no_more_rows THEN
        CLOSE projects_cur;
        LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;

SET Project_List_val=CONCAT(`Project_Number_val`,'_List')
```

-

```
> ---> **Please check am I doing CONCAT correct here?**


Insert Into test (Panel_Id) select Panel_Id from Project_List_val where Project_Number_val='9';  

> --->**Is this taking 9_List as table name?**


    SET loop_cntr = loop_cntr + 1;
  END LOOP the_loop;


  select num_rows, loop_cntr;


END $$# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).


DELIMITER
```

Any suggestions?
Hi All,

I have a variable in stored procedure named Project_Number and it is of varchar type.

My Requirement is "for each project number query the table project_Number_List get results from list and insert into other table"

Lets say, Project_Number might be like this 22,21,34,43,434
corresponding tables I need to query is something like this 22_List, 21_List,34_List .....

I'm using cursor to loop through the Project_Number but my problem is how to mix the project_number and _list i.e., 22_list to query the table 22_List

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with this :

```
SET Project_List_val=CONCAT(Project_Number_val,'_List')
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Insert Into test (Manthan_Panel_Id) select Manthan_Panel_Id from Project_List_va' at line 41

Comment: Working fine. I didn't put ; at the end of statement.

Comment: After calling the stored procedure it is showing this error.#1146 - Table 'panel_rs.project_list_val' doesn't exist. which means it is not taking variable value it is taking name as table name. How to change it to take value as table name.

Answer (score 4):

```
SET Project_List_val=CONCAT(Project_Number_val,'_List');
```

Don't put the single quotation For Project_Number_val vairable.

Answer (score 2):

you var call is wrong, try this:

```
 SET Project_List_val = CONCAT(Project_Number_val,'_List')
```